how to resample a timeindex data frame?
I have a code that gathers data obtained from various experiments.
It presents two columns : one is timestamp - measured every minute - and the other measures an activity in the form of an float.
I was trying to transform the absolute time to a relative time ie from "2020-04-25 11:51:30" to "Day1 experiment : 11:51:30" in order to **compare one experience with other samples on the same relative hours and minute of the day. **
And then, I tried to resample the data over a 20min timespan since the sensors delivered responses every minute and it creates too much datapoints to be vizualized and compared.
To do so, I tried to extract day, hours, minute and seconds using  dt, to create a "relative timestamp" and finally resample the number of data points from  every minute to a mean point collected every 20 minute.
To create the relative timestamp, I thought of concatenating the different values I have with DT but unfortunately it doesn't even appear in the CSV file.
import pandas as pd 
import glob
import re

all_files = glob.glob('condition_*.csv')

li = []

for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, usecols=[0,2])
    num = [int(x) for x in re.split('_|[.]',filename) if x.isdigit()]
    df = df.rename(columns={'timestamp':'timestamp_%s' %num[0], 'activity': 'activity_%s' %num[0]})
    df['timestamp_%s' %num[0]] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp_%s' %num[0]])
    
    df['timestamp_hour_%s' %num[0]]=df['timestamp_%s' %num[0]].dt.hour
    df['timestamp_minute_%s' %num[0]]=df['timestamp_%s' %num[0]].dt.minute
    df['timestamp_day_%s' %num[0]]=df['timestamp_%s' %num[0]].dt.day
    df['timestamp_day_absolute %s' %num[0]]= (df['timestamp_%s' %num[0]]-df['timestamp_%s' %num[0]][0]).dt.days
    df['absolute_date_%s' %num[0]] ='Day'+df['timestamp_day_absolute %s' %num[0]].astype(str) +' '+ df['timestamp_hour_%s' %num[0]].astype(str) + '_' + df['timestamp_minute_%s' %num[0]].astype(str)
    df=df.set_index('timestamp_%s' %num[0])
    df=df.resample("20min").mean()
    li.append(df)
    #df['absolute_date_%s' %num[0]] = pd.DataFrame({'hour':df['timestamp_hour_%s' %num[0]], 'minute':df['timestamp_minute_%s' %num[0]], 'day':df['timestamp_day_absolute %s' %num[0]]})
    #cols = ['timestamp_hour_%s' %num[0], 'timestamp_minute_%s' %num[0], 'timestamp_day_absolute %s' %num[0]]
    #df['absolute_date_%s' %num[0]] = df[cols].apply(lambda row: '_'.join(row.values.astype(str)), axis=1)


frame = pd.concat(li, axis=1)

frame.to_csv('testabsolute_condition_date.csv')

csv file obtained not displaying the absolute date serie
